# Differerence between Transparent and Black background in RGB

Tags: android, colors, background, rgb

Hi there I have a question, I want to know the background of an image and determine if the background is light or dark, the problem is that if the background is dark I want to use white images, and if the background is transparent I want to use black icons. Im using this method to determine if the background is dark or light:

`public static boolean isDark(float[] hsl) { // @Size(3)
        return hsl[2] < 0.8f; //Use 0.8f for a better precision
    }`

The problem is that this method can´t know the difference between both backgrounds (dark or transparent)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hsla, the "a" is for alpha. This way you can check if the background is transparent or not. Likely your method that converts to hsl is ignoring the alpha parameter.